# Taking too long to execute code for largest prime factor

Tags: python, compilation

I was trying Project Euler Problem 3: What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143 ? My code is working for random 4 digit numbers. However my code is just not compiling. It has been 15 minutes now.

I think this has something to do with "efficiency of algorithms". I am about to join college for Computer Science and Engineering course so I thought it would be a great idea if I practiced coding in Python. Is my code not efficient? Should I study CLRS now before going any further? I have already completed the basics of Python (from Udacity).

```py
#What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143 ?
factorlist=[]
def prime(num):                                             #primetesterfunction
    primecount=0
    for factors in range(2,num):
        if num%factors==0:
            return False
        else:
            primecount+=1
    if primecount==num-2:
        return True

num=int(input("Enter Number: "))
for x in range(2,num+1):
    if num%x==0 and prime(x)==True:
        factorlist.append(x)
    else:
        continue
print("The largest prime factor of {} is {}".format(num,factorlist[-1]))
```

It's been 18 minutes now and still no result...

Comment: There's no such thing as *compilation* in Python. You probably mean *execution*.

Comment: It shouldn't be a surprise that a nested loop with that many iterations takes a long time

Comment: [Cross site duplicate](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/104997)

Comment: No one said your question was wrong, if you'd clicked on either of the links I posted instead of being rude you'd have seen they're the *exact same question*

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as *compilation* in Python; you probably mean *execution*.

It takes less than a second to get the answer:

```
n = 600851475143

p = 2

while n > 1:
    if n % p == 0:
        while n % p == 0:
            n /= p
        largest = p
    p += 1

print(largest) # 6857
```

So your code is either extremely inefficient, or it is plain wrong.

Comment: Pyc files? I've edited out all of the unneeded commentary

Comment: Yeah look I don't know the first thing about "compilation" or "execution" technically. I thought that they all mean execution loosely.

And my code is not wrong. I have tested it for many 4 digit numbers. And I don't understand why you got your answer in 2 seconds. That is why I asked whether I should read theoretical aspects of efficiency.

Comment: I do understand your code though. Its neat.